# Getting cell value loses the comma in the string?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm using the following line to read a value from an Excel worksheet:

```
cellValue = (sheet.Cells[row, 13] as Range).Value.ToString();
```

In this particular case, the value in the cell looks like this: `"100,110"`.  Basically, two number separated by a comma.

When I read the cell value, my `cellValue` variable value ends up being: `"100110"`.

I have to have the comma because I need to split the numbers into an array to use later on (in this instance, I'd have an array with two elements; `100 and 110)`.

What can I do to so that when I read the cell, the value that I get is `"100,110" instead of "100110"?`

Comment: Because `Value` returns a double if the cell is a numeric cell.  Use `.Text` instead.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  If you make this an answer, I can choose it for the answer to the question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Value` property returns a `double` for numeric values (including dates) and does not take formatting into consideration.  It's probably translating your comma-delimited list as a single number.  You can use the `.Text` property to extract the formatted value.